# How to show half of the elements from an unordered list using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a website where I need to show list of images in a page. However, the page needs to show half of the images from the list and when user clicks "show more" button, then it should show the rest of the images from the list. How can I do that using javascript? Following the the html I am using.

```
<div class="pic_holder">
        <ul>

        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/6001.jpg"></a>
            <span class="text-content "><span>
                <div class="head_name">Place Name</div>
                <div class="subhead_name">Place Name</div>
            </span></span>

        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/600_O2.jpg"></a>
            <span class="text-content"><span>
                <div class="head_name">Place Name</div>
                <div class="subhead_name">Place Name</div>
            </span></span>


        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/600-v4.jpg"></a>
            <span class="text-content"><span>
                <div class="head_name ">Place Name</div>
                <div class="subhead_name ">Place Name</div>
            </span></span>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/6001.jpg"></a>
            <span class="text-content"><span>
                <div class="head_name ">Place Name</div>
                <div class="subhead_name ">Place Name</div>
            </span></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/600_O2.jpg"></a>
            <span class="text-content"><span>
                <div class="head_name ">Place Name</div>
                <div class="subhead_name ">Place Name</div>
            </span></span>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/600-v4.jpg"></a>
            <span class="text-content"><span>
                <div class="head_name ">Place Name</div>
                <div class="subhead_name ">Place Name</div>
            </span></span>
        </li>
```

```
  <div class="show_more">
        <h2>Show More</h2>

    </div>
```

Comment: where is the js code did you try something?

Answer (score 3):

The solution should be:

```
var $items = $("ul li");
$items.hide();
$items.slice(0, Math.floor($items.length/2)).show();
```

In your "show more" button you only need to show all items.

```
var $items = $("ul li");
$items.show();
```